# Onedrive special App Folder - creating a new folder

Tags: c#, onedrive, special-folders

I'm working with the OneDrive SDK and have successfully managed to get a reference to my special App folder.

```
  _appFolder = await OneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
```

From here I want to create a sub folder called say "Deep Purple".

Looking at the C# example code I can do this using:

```
var folderToCreate = new Item { Name = artistName, Folder = new Folder() };
        var newFolder = await OneDriveClient
                                  .Drive
                                  .Items[itemId]
                                  .Children
                                  .Request()
                                  .AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

But I'm thinking I already have a reference down to Items[itemId] (my _appFolder is of type Item), so I can just use:

```
var myNewFolder = await _appFolder.Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

But no, as you can see by this image I don't have a Request option.

[image: No Request() Option]

I'm clearly misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using a `Model` (object representations of response data) and trying to get a `Request`, which is only returned from the type `RequestBuilder`. You are close, though! If you want to add a file to the children of your app folder (which is of type `Folder`), then your request would look like this:

```
var newFolder = await oneDriveClient
    .Drive
    .Items[_appFolder.Id]
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

At its core, the SDK relies on the `OneDriveClient` object to generate requests because it knows how to do things like authentication and URL generation. The `Model`s are just containers for information returned from the service. You can use the information in those containers in concert with the client to generate any request you need.